# A combinatorial sum

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, summation

- Any idea to evaluate the sum
  $$
  \sum_{j=m}^{k}\frac{\binom{m}{2m - j\,\,}}{\binom{k}{j}}
  \quad\mbox{with}\quad m \leq k < 2m - 1.
  $$
- I have found the sum for $k=2m-1$. In fact, it is verified that
  $$
  \sum_{j = m}^{2m - 1}\ \frac{\binom{m}{2m-j\,\,}}
  {\binom{2m - 1\,\,}{j}} = 2m\left(H_{2m} - H_{m}\right),
  $$
  where $H_{j}$ is the $j$-th harmonic number.

Answer (score 1):

For a short time, I hoped to be able to express the result in terms of hypergeometric functions but I failed.

If we let $k=m+n$, the problem reduces to
$$S_n=\sum_{j=m}^{m+n} \frac{\Gamma (j+1)\,\,\Gamma (m+n+1-j)}{\Gamma (m+n+1)} \,\binom{m}{2 m-j} $$ which can write
$$S_n=\frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{n!\ \Gamma(m+n+1)} P_{n}(m)$$ where $P_n$ is a  polynomial of degree $2n$ (it does not seem to be factorable for any $n$).

The very first are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & m^2+m+1 \\
 2 & m^4+2 m^3+m^2+4 \\
 3 & m^6+3 m^5-2 m^4-9 m^3+13 m^2+18 m+36 \\
 4 & m^8+4 m^7-10 m^6-44 m^5+53 m^4+184 m^3+100 m^2+576
\end{array}
\right)$$

I have not been able to find any pattern for the coefficients [except that the constant term is $(n!)^2$ and that the coefficient of $m^{2n}$ is $1$ (!!) ].

The only thing I observed is that, if $n$ is even, the term is $m$ is systematically missing.

Without any proof of it, I do not think that a closed form could exist for a general $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here [maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.net)'s Zeilberger package (take a peek at [Petkovsek, Wilf, Zeilberger "A = B"](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html) for the gory details) says your sum isn't Gosper summable. That means there is no simple closed form for it.

Comment: Thank you much, I suppossed that